# What's the antonym of "prioritize"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, antonyms, is-it-a-word, negative-prefixes

If someone is asked to do something important, they might say "I'll prioritize that". But if someone is asked to put something aside to work on something else more important, what could they say?

In the past I've used "de-prioritize", but I'm not sure if that's actually a word. Is it a word? Is there some other way to get this point across?

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deprioritize

Comment: @mplungjan I guess you answered my question :) Post an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Neither can you ask not someone answer what is general reference (that which can found in a standard dictionary or source.)

Comment: In the Agile software development world, working on a goal and then changing course to do other tasks first is commonly called [punting](http://jessewarden.com/2008/11/agile-chronicles-5-acceptance-criteria-punting.html). Usage: "That feature has been punted to a future release.", "This is taking more time than we originally budgeted, so the team is considering punting it."

Comment: @mplungjan if it is off-topic why post an answer?

Comment: @msam I asked him to, and I'm grateful that he did :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Deprioritize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deprioritize) is a word so feel free to use it :)

Comment: to deprioritize something it must have been previously prioritized

Comment: @msam Everything has some priority, even if that happens to be the same as everything else.  "Deprioritize" can be used even if something has not been explicitly prioritized - it would then just mean "after everything else".

Answer (score 2):

*Put on the back burner* can be used if the item previously had priority which should now be reduced:

> *put item B on the back burner it while you work on item A*

as well as if it had none

> *here's a new work item B, but leave this on the back burner/give it low priority until you finish with A*

Comment: There is also a verb form - *to back burner* something.

Answer (score 1):

You could use  **demote**

> to lower someone or something in rank or position:

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/demote

Answer (score 0):

How about *overlook*, *disorganize*, or *neglect*?

Comment: Those are good - but I'm looking specifically for something that means "It's still on my to do list, but at a lower priority than it was before".

Comment: In that case, [deprioritize](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/deprioritize) sounds good to me.

Comment: How about 'Put aside'?

Comment: Postpone might also be useful

Comment: I think "overlook" and "neglect" sound too passive for the intended meaning.

Answer (score 0):

I like the word **bump** here.

> Usage:
>
> Building the tower on the bridge was the number one priority but we
>   are going to have to bump that down until we get the materials.

Comment: Your example is really *bump*... *down* though - "bump" alone could mean increase or decrease the priority.